# Чем отличается массив массивов и двумерный массив

Tags: c#

Чем отличаются эти конструкции?

```
int[][] a1;
int[,] a2;
```

Comment: В том, что у массива массивов внутренние размерности не заданы и позволяют [создавать неравномерные зубчатые массивы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2s05feca(v=vs.80).aspx). У двумерного массива размерность всегда одинакова.

Comment: очень подробная инфа по `arrays C#` https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1429/arrays#t=201708191929159227497

Comment: Тем, что первое — это линейный массив линейных массивов, а второе — двумерный массив?

Comment: @AlexKrass: А ещё у первого столбцы нужно инициализировать отдельно, а у второго нет. А ещё у первого размеры столбцов могут меняться, а у второго нет. А ещё первый является `IEnumerable<int>`, а второй нет. И ещё бесконечное число отличий. Это просто два разных, не связанных между собой понятия.

Comment: @VladD когда я пытаюсь объяснять подобные вещи, я предпочитаю думать о структурах данных. Поэтому один для меня матрица, а второй для меня массив в котором можно хранить другие массивы. Еще лучше это передают картинки для [многомерного массива](http://www.w3computing.com/vb2008/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/06/2.6.vb-one-two-three-dimensional-arrays.jpg) и [массива массивов](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Arrays-dontumindit/array12.gif). Мне кажется общая картина на первом этапе важнее, чем непосредственная реализация.

Comment: @AlexKrass: По факту: у нас есть две совершенно различные структуры данных, из которых одну можно использовать как эмуляцию другой. Точно так же можно было бы спросить о разнице между `int[]` и `Dictionary<int, int>` (который тоже _можно_ использовать для отображения индекса в значение). С моей точки зрения, раз структуры разные, то имеет больше смысла спрашивать, что между ними _общего_.

Comment: @VladD просто мне кажется автору не нужны настолько глубокие вещи и настолько буквальный ответ)) Поэтому я и ответил просто, без деталей реализации - что позволяет делать одно и что другое в общей картине. В остальном Вы конечно совершенно правы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Давайте посмотрим поближе...**

### Двумерный массив.

Очень популярное *(и самое точное)* представление это самая обыкновенная таблица. Вот возьмем для примера таблицу от **Google**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот самая простая таблица. В пересечении столбцов и строк я записал их в виде:

`[Номер строки, Номер столбца]`

Так вот. Любой двумерный массив можно изобразить визуально в виде таблицы.

В **C#** это выглядит вот так:

```
 //Пример с таблицей умножения: 

 int [,] arr = new int [3, 3];
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
     {
          arr [i, k] = i * k;
     }
 }
```

И вот этот массив мы должны изобразить в таком виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверяем...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю с двумерным массивом понятно. Потому что массив массивов не настолько простой как двумерный или трёхмерный массив *(его можно представить в виде "кубика Рубика")*

### Массив массивов.

Название что-то говорит да не договаривает. Этот тип массивов может очень сильно знаком каждому из нас. Да, это тот самый пакет с пакетами на кухне. Думаю мои дальнейшие комментарии будут бесполезны после такого сравнения)

В одном большом массиве *(пакете)* находятся другие пакеты которые могут содержать в себе что-то свое:

В **С#** массив массивов создается вот так:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];
//Тут число 3 это то количество массивов которое будет содержать этот "общий" массив
jaggedArray[0] = new int[5]; //А вот тут число 5 это размер первого массива из этой кучи из 3 массивов.
jaggedArray[1] = new int[2]; //А тут уже второй массив и его размер это 2 числа.
```

Думаю мои пояснения хоть немного приблизил вас к пониманию принципов работы с этими двумя типами массивов.

**SeeSharp**