# Как в C# с помощью LINQ сделать выборку классов с одинаковым значением в поле?

Tags: c#, linq

Например, есть JSON

```
var products = JArray.Parse(@"[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Product 1',
    variantId: 1
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Product 2',
    variantId: 1
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Product 3',
    variantId: 1
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Product 4',
    variantId: 4
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Product 5',
    variantId: 4
}]");
```

Как мне получить массив всех массивов, `variantId` которых равен `1`? То есть, в итоге, что бы было это:

```
var products = JArray.Parse(@"[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Product 1',
    variantId: 1
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Product 2',
    variantId: 1
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Product 3',
    variantId: 1
}]");
```

Comment: Чем отличается первый фрагмент кода от второго кроме количества элементов в массиве? Если ничем, удалите второй, он вводит в заблуждение. Вопрос можно редактировать. Кстати, у вас синтаксически неправильный JSON, его невозможно распарсить, будет исключение. Для экранирования кавычек в @verbatim string используйте двойные кавычки `""`.

Comment: "кроме количества элементов в массиве"

@aepot, так тем и отличаются. В этом и суть вопроса. Вы невнимательно прочитали условие или я не сильно доходчиво изложил вопрос?

Comment: ["массив массивов"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/911231/373567) = "выборка из массива" = "отфильтровать массив"? Конечно же я невнимательно прочитал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ответ 1

Возможно, вы знаете то значение `variantId`, по которому хотите фильтровать. Если так, то фильтрация осуществляется с помощью метода `Where`:

```
var filtered = products.Where(x => x.variantId == 1);
```

Или, в облегчённом синтаксисе:

```
var filtered = from product in products
               where product.variantId = 1
               select product;
```

### Ответ 2

Возможно, вы хотите получить все массивы с разными значениями `variantId`, которые встречаются в массиве. В этом случае вам нужна *группировка*:

```
var groups = products.GroupBy(x => x.variantId);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key); // уникальное значение ключа группы, в нашем случае variantId
    foreach (var elements in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"id: {group.id}, name: {group.name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно!

Comment: Откуда берется у объекта `JToken` свойство `variantId`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, поле `variantId` было задано примером в моём вопросе.

Comment: @НикитаГалактионов я понимаю, что у вас в `json` - строке есть поле `variantId`, но откуда у `x` (который является типом `JToken`) появляется `variantId` ? Это ведь не `dynamic` - переменная. У меня код `products.Where(x => x.variantId == 1);` выдает ошибку компиляции.